# having problems with my first ruby test code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new to ruby and am getting accustomed to the development tools. I am making use of the irb and and have ran my first helloword.Also done the same using the cmd prompt.
I have the following function which keeps returning an error

```
def palindrome2?(string)
    puts "hello"
    regex = /^[a-zA-Z]/
    string = gsub(regex,'').downcase
    mirror = string.reverse
    reformat == mirror
 end
```

it keeps returning a  undefined method `gsub' for main:Object error.How do I solve this

Comment: Call `gsub` on the `string` parameter: `string.gsub`. You instead call it on the main object (top level object in ruby).

Comment: @Alex Kliuchnikau undoubtedly meant to say "object", not "parameter".

Answer (score 0):

In your case you forgot to call gsub method on string

String Palindrome

```
class String
 def palindrome?
  self.downcase == reverse.downcase
 end
end

"baB".palindrome? #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, gsub method on string returns nil if no changes were made. So if your string is a proper word without any no-word character, for example "fijowejg", "filsijdf".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, '') will return nil. After that downcase method cannot be run on the nil object.

So you can't chain methods gsub and downcase in this order.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub